# GraphQL Query to Fetch all Image Components for a Publication

Tags: multimedia, graphql, tridion-docs, dxd-11.1, pca

I want to fetch all the Image Components inside a Publication from DXD. I am using the below Query which gives me *all* the Components(Topics) inside a Publication but I want just Images.

Any idea of how to filter the Images from all the components in the result?

```
{
  items(
    filter: {
      itemTypes:[COMPONENT]
      namespaceIds: [2]
    publicationIds:[8915]
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        itemId
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a customMeta under the filter section:

```
customMeta: { key: "ishtype.object.value", value: "ISHIllustration" }
```

You may also be able to do this in code, using the Public Content API (PCA) client. Something like this:

```
var client = ApiClientFactory.Instance.CreateClient();

InputComponentPresentationFilter inputFilter = new InputComponentPresentationFilter();
inputFilter.CustomMeta.Key = "ishtype.object.value";
inputFilter.CustomMeta.Value = "ISHIllustration";
inputFilter.CustomMeta.ValueType = CustomMetaValueType.STRING;

var imageComponents = client.GetComponentPresentations(ContentNamespace.Docs,
                                                       pubId,
                                                       inputFilter,
                                                       new Pagination(),
                                                       null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Saurabh - I believe you can filter on schema ID or Title too?

schema: {
  title: SCHEMA_TITLE
}